# Calculate and plot residuals variance of a regression, per year, using R

Tags: r, statistics, economics

I calculated a linear model, with the `lm()` function. I know how to extract the residuals, using the `resid()` function, but I would like to calculate the values of the residuals variance by year and plot it.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show us the steps you've already taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a data frame out of the residuals and the year, `aggreagte` it and make a `barplot`.

```
fdf <- data.frame(resid=fit$residuals, year=fit$model$year)
res <- aggregate(resid ~ year, fdf, var)
barplot(resid ~ year, res)
```

[image]

---

*Toy data*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- transform(cbind.data.frame(year=1:5, x=rnorm(500)), y=.5 * x + rnorm(500))
fit <- lm(y ~ x + year, dat)
```